# SQL Server : extracting the middle of a string

Tags: sql-server

I have a column in SQL Server that looks like so -

```
columnA
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Vendor=ABCCorp,FTPAddress=ftp.abccorp.com,Filename=index.html.yyyymmdd,Filename_Encrypted=index.html.ppg.yyyymmdd,Filename_Compressed=index.html.yyyymmdd.zip,LocalPath=\\san\folder\folder\yyyy\mm\dd,RemotePath=/
```

I want to be able to extract the `Filename` from this column. The problem is that, due to the change in length (the vendor, ftp may be different) I can't tell it to just start at a specific point.

Ideally I want it to start after the 3rd '=' and end after the 4th ','.  How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CHARINDEX` function to get the location of `Filename=`.

Try this:

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @SearchToken VARCHAR(25)
DECLARE @StartLocation INT
SET @String = 'Vendor=ABCCorp,FTPAddress=ftp.abccorp.com,Filename=index.html.yyyymmdd,Filename_Encrypted=index.html.ppg.yyyymmdd,Filename_Compressed=index.html.yyyymmdd.zip,LocalPath=\\san\folder\folder\yyyy\mm\dd,RemotePath=/'
SET @SearchToken = 'Filename='
SET @StartLocation = CHARINDEX(@SearchToken, @String)
SELECT SUBSTRING(@String, @StartLocation + LEN(@SearchToken), CHARINDEX(',', @String, @StartLocation) - (@StartLocation + LEN(@SearchToken)))
```

It extracts what you need by finding the location of `Filename=` then taking the substring starting after that and up to the next comma `,`.

Comment: That gets me to the beginning of Filename= so you're saying I'd need to repeat from the other direction (ie. CHARINDEX ',Filename_Encrypted=') and then trim those numbers off to get 'Filename=index.html.yyyymmdd' and then do a final trim from that?

Comment: I just had to reply that I love you.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a user defined function to split the string and then split the string twice.

This is the function I have for splitting a string:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[buildTableFromSplit] ( @str  nvarchar(max), @delimiter VARCHAR(50) ) 
         RETURNS @myTable TABLE (ID int identity (1,1), split nvarchar(max))
AS    BEGIN 

DECLARE @x xml  

SELECT @X = CONVERT(xml,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@Str,@delimiter,'</s><s>') + '</s></root>')

INSERT INTO @myTable(split)
SELECT [Value] = T.c.value('.','varchar(max)')
FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T(c)

    return  
END
```

Then I would call it like so:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @str = 'Vendor=ABCCorp,FTPAddress=ftp.abccorp.com,Filename=index.html.yyyymmdd,Filename_Encrypted=index.html.ppg.yyyymmdd,Filename_Compressed=index.html.yyyymmdd.zip,LocalPath=\\san\folder\folder\yyyy\mm\dd,RemotePath=/'
DECLARE @delimiter VARCHAR(50)
SET @delimiter = ','

    SELECT split FROM dbo.buildTableFromSplit((SELECT split FROM dbo.buildTableFromSplit(@str, @delimiter) WHERE LEFT(split,9) = 'FileName='), '=')
    WHERE id =2
```